# can't get zend public subfolders using virtualhost

Tags: image, zend-framework, localhost, virtualhost, subdirectory

I create a Zend project. My images are in folder public/icons and they available when I run project using url `http://localhost/zendproject/public/icons/image.png` but when I use virtualhost `http://zend.gameblog` I can't get this image by url `http://zendgameblog/icons/image.png`.
 Browser says "403 Forbidden" and I can't understand why. I also have public/captcha folder and any image from this location always available by url `http://zend.gameblog/captcha/image.png`.

I use: win7 x86, WAMP, zend framework 1.12, Zend Studio 9.0.4. Some of resources and folders I created manually not via Zend Studio.

Please help me and tell whether I will have such problems when I'll run my project at real server?

Comment: Check permission of the project and images folder.

Answer (score 0):

For all css, js and img on web site use [baseUrl helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl):

```
$this->baseUrl('/icons/image.png');
//or
$this->baseUrl('/css/css_file.css');
```

and for all links on web site use [URL View Helper](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/04/zend-framework-url-view-helper/):  $this->url(...)

Comment: There was some error when I created that folder I think. I just deleted it and created it again and all works fine now.